# Changing items in a list created from JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list

I'm still new to JavaScript so apologies if any of this is unclear - I have got the following code, which dynamically creates a list from a JSON array (rolesData) and puts the data from "roles" into a list (see a couple of examples of what is in the array below). Which particular roles are placed into the list is determined at random (i.e. `document.body.appendChild(createList(rolesData[~~(Math.random()*rolesData.length)].roles));` This works fine, and the list is created as expected (i.e. if the random number is 0, then the roles for "John Smith" will added to the list.

However, I now want to create an added functionality so that the list can be changed (for example by clicking a button) and the data from a different name is changed in the list (i.e. if the random number changes to a 1 then the roles for "Mary Taylor" will be added). The problem I have is that there are different numbers of roles for each of the people in the list - so John has 3 roles, Mary has 4 and so on.

So I am struggling to think of how I can create a function that changes the list that is also able to change the number of items in the list. I had tried to do it by assigning an id to each list item that is created in the initial table and then doing getElementById and changing it that way - the problem with that obviously though is that if there are only 3 list items created in the initial table, then there will only be 3 id's created - so if trying to add a fourth item there is no id to get (and I'm sure there are other issues with that approach as well). So I'm a little bit stuck on how I can do this - any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const rolesData = [{
   "name": "John Smith",
   "title": "project manager",
   "roles": ["Planning and Defining Scope", "Activity Planning and Sequencing", "Resource Planning"],
  },
  {
   "name": "Mary Taylor",
   "title": "test analyst",
   "roles": ["design and develop tests for software and systems to detect faults", "analyse the defects and bugs to identify what is causing them", "track the success of the solutions", "keep software and systems documentation up to date"],
  }
  ];

const createList = data => {
  const list = document.createElement("ul");

 data.forEach(e => {
   const listItem = document.createElement("li");
   listItem.innerHTML = e;
   list.appendChild(listItem);
 });

 return list;
};

document.body.appendChild(createList(rolesData[~~(Math.random()*rolesData.length)].roles));
```

(This is the approach I had been trying to take, which obviously won't work).

```
const createList = data => {
const list = document.getElementById("featuredList");
count = 1;
data.forEach(e => {
 const listItem = document.getElementByID("listItem" + count);
 listItem.innerHTML = e;
 list.appendChild(listItem);
 count++;
});
return list;
};
```

Comment: Your problem is that you have an initial list that you want to replace with another list that may have a different number of elements? Why don't you remove all elements of the list and create one new instead of replacing the contents of each one?

Comment: @JaviMollá I hadn't thought of that option - I had just been thinking about how to get the element and change it. But that will work nicely - thanks a lot, that's really helpful.

Comment: May I post it as an answer and you mark it as selected?

Comment: @JaviMollá Yep, absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the list and create a new one instead of replacing its contents